# My Android 6.0 phone changes the MAC address every time I log into a WLAN; how can I stop it?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, mac-address

I have a rooted Cubot Max (Not Max 2) Android 6.0 phone that has an interesting habit: it changes the MAC Address every time I log into a WLAN. The WLAN MAC address usually looks like `00:08:22:xx:xx:xx`. The second part is random. In the beginning, it was funny, but now I want to stop it.

I read the MAC address from Settings > About the phone > Status. There is no spoofing software on it. It seems that this is a normal reaction of hackers in China, they do not like constant MAC addresses.

Do you know if there is any secret setting there I could take a look at?

Answer (score 2):

The randomization of MAC Address is a security feature of Android 6.0, the OS changes the MAC address when a background scan of the network is initiated.

> When a device running Android 6.0 (API level 23) initiates a background Wi-Fi or Bluetooth scan, the operation is visible to external devices as originating from a randomized MAC address.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes

Here you may find details about the randomization:
https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/wifi-mac-randomization-behavior?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

In current Android versions, each SSID has its own setting for randomization.  It is possible that this may be present in rooted Android6 as well.   To stop the randomization -

- Go into **Settings**
- Select **Connections**
- Select **Wifi** (long press if necessary)
- Select the SSID you want to fix it for
- Once connected, press the Gear Wheel
- Press on **View more** at the bottom of the screen
- Scroll Down until you see **MAC Address Type**
- Its a drop down, change it from Random to  **Phone MAC**

[image]